# Keep getting rejected by interviewers

Tags: interviewing, job-search, austria

I'm currently living/working in Austria, and I'm Egyptian, and that's for two years.

I got about 7 interviews in the last two years, face to face, and I got rejected. They never say a reason, even they never tested me technically, they just asking general questions, HR, and if you have skills in this or this and mostly I do.

I'm really wondering, and that's really depressing, should I leave the country or what for a better IT Job industry like UK, ireland ?

I would like to know what could be the reason for having that common behavior.

Most of the jobs that I apply for are junior to middle career, so I have never requested something that is high in responsibility. 
I'm an EE graduated in 2007, and mostly I worked for Computer Vision, Games and Embedded Software, Security..etc.

Some of the replies:

1) We can not provide you with a positive response, but we wish you the best for  your future career.

2) Thanks for the follow-up, I am very late at catching up with applications in the new year. I value your engagement in keeping interested in our job offer. We’ve decided on another candidate this time but will happily consider your application in the future.

3) it’s our personal impression that you will not fit into our existing design team. Additionally we missed important personal properties.  In our team everyone enigneer has to rely on each other team member. Personally I would not rely on the results of your statements or work.

4) This one after really promising with a job offer, they sent that after 4 months of the interview.
Dear Mr, we would like to thank you for your interest. We are sorry to let you know that our company does not have any vacancy at the moment. 
We do however retain your details in our files which we periodically review when considering potential candidates for other vacancies.  "

After getting suggestions by editing the question
My question is it normal that you have about 8 job interviews and you only get offer by two ?
What is the acceptable ejection ratio?

Comment: Hey Mahmoud, and welcome back to [workplace.se]. As explained in our [help/on-topic], this isn't the best place to ask about where you should get a job, or what sort of job you could look for. Other than asking whether you should move to another country, there doesn't seem to be a question in your post so there are many people voting to close. If you could [edit] it to ask a question within the guidelines in our [help/dont-ask] you will get better answers. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer to your core question, what **could** be the reason, is: Anything. Only the people rejecting your application can know, why. If you're genuinely interested in the answer to that question, it's better placed with these people, or possibly good friends and former colleagues who really know you.

Comment: We don't know if you're qualified for the jobs you were applying to, nor do we know what (if anything) the companies that didn't hire you were thinking. Even with the edit, this isn't really the type of question that is a good fit for this site as it is asking for speculation, not *"practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"* as explained in our [help/dont-ask].

Comment: @Mahmoud That largely depends on the particular niche, set of companies and area you're applying in. In the startup field here in Berlin I wouldn't say there's a preference for german speakers. But german isn't the prevalent office language in these types of companies, either.

Comment: I understand what your question is, it just isn't something this format is designed to answer. 'Average' depends on so many factors that we can't possibly hope to cover it (too broad). Even if we narrow it down to 'in Austria in the IT industry' it would depend on the skills of the person. What does 'average' matter when there will be people on either side of average, and very few people whose experience exactly matches that?

Comment: If you're an Egyptian, you know what to do ;-)

Comment: ``What is the acceptable ejection ratio?`` Back when there was an oversupply of developers in Finland, the ratio was quite close to 100:1 (I wish I was exaggerating!). But in a healthy market, I would say 5:1 is close to "normal", based on empirical evidence among my peers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - don't give up!

Second, those replies are really just a nice way of saying 'No'. Nearly always they're standard messages so don't look too much into them. If you want personal feedback, ask for it. Send an email like:

Dear Mr X,

Thank you for interviewing me for the position of [position] [insert a reference to the amount of time ago].

[Ask for feedback nicely]

I wish you good luck with your new hire.

Sincerely,

[You]

Third, where did you graduate? If it was in Egypt (or anywhere else in the Middle East or Africa for that matter), they might have (subconsciously) doubts about the quality of your university (and hence, the value of your degree).

To answer 'is it normal', I have no experience related to jobs in your field, but I'd say that's not abnormal, keep trying.

Comment: Thanks for your words. but I have worked for two years in Austria, and for Saudi Arabia two years. it's really weird

Comment: 1, 2 and 4 certainly sound like standard messages. I don't know if 3 is so standard.

Comment: @starsplusplus 3 is not a standard, I asked for feedback.

Comment: Ah okay. When they gave you that feedback did you ask what they meant by "we missed important personal properties" or why they felt "I would not rely on the results of your statements or work"? Those sound like things that need clarifying if that's the feedback that you're getting.

Comment: @starsplusplus I felt it as an insult, so I didn't ask more. Tomorrow I have interview too, I wish it would be ok. :(